# How to run Different .kt file/Class in same src folder?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am new in kotlin , I started to learn Kotlin Language by installing **intellij IDEA** , now the issue is when i want to run second `.kt` file by run button its only showing what i had run first `.kt` file .

[image: Image One Here]

[image: Image Two here]

Always showing Run `HelloWorld.kt`, I want to run `Addition.kt`

I am no able to run new crated class in kotlin, it's only showing the first class what I had run first time in the project.

Comment: Does your `Addition.kt` have a `main` function, too ?

Comment: fun main(args:Array <String>){
    print(10+10)
}

Comment: yes, have main fun

Answer (score 2):

Just use the tiny Kotlin button on the left side of your `main` method to run this one. This should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can "edit" your run configuration to point to the desired `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class to run using the `edit configurations` panel
[image: screenshot]
There you can create a new configuration to run the second class or edit the default configuration to start the second class.

But this may be unnecessarily complicated for a beginner and is rarely needed for any project.
You should probably try either:

- Just run your multiple test statements in the same main method
- Create a top level function in any class and call that from the main method
- Start learning to use classes and objects and create them from the main method.